# How can I connect multiple routers to a modem that only supports one router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet, modem

My modem only supports one WAN connection going to the router all the other ports on the modem have been blocked somehow. I already contacted my ISP and asked them about why the Ethernet cable wasn't working and they said that the modem they provide only supports one WAN port connection.

So I was wondering if I got a Ethernet splitter, like for example the TP-Link Ethernet Splitter (Image below), and connect my two routers to the Ethernet splitter would that work, and if it did, are there any drawbacks?

**Extra Information**

1. My 1st Router is a router provided by my ISP
2. My 2nd Router is a TP-LINK Archer C9
3. The cable connecting the modem to my second router is a CAT. 7 Ethernet cable

[image: TP-LINK Ethernet Splitter]

Comment: A typical arrangement would be to connect modem<-->ISP router<-->other router.  What are you trying to accomplish by connecting two routers directly to a modem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common layout for consumers wanting to use their own hardware is to do the following:

```
Modem <==> ISPRouter <==> OwnRouter
```

You would then turn off features on the ISP router that would interfere with your service e.g wireless, DHCP and so on.

Your isp may support a configuration like this:

```
Modem <==> OwnRouter
```

But you would have to inquire with their support and see if they allow a customers own router to be connected and used.

Some ISP devices come with a "pass through mode" or modem only mode, which makes them a dumb relay.

If your ISP router does not support this form of configuration officially, you will likely be stuck with your router connected to a 100mbit port, not a problem if your internet speed is below that however. Some ISP devices (The virgin media home hub for example) Have a dedicated port for what they call "Modem mode" where the superhub performs the actions of a modem, and turns off all other features. Your own router can then perform the tasks you wish.

Comment: Thanks, but would my primary idea work of connecting a Ethernet cable splitter?

Comment: Possibly, I couldn't say without knowing how that particular modem worked. It may only expect 1 device on the other side.